# django URL mapping?

Tags: django, django-urls

Newbie to django and python.  Trying to get some example calendar code up and running but having problems with URL mapping.  When I try to run the admin page (or any page), I get:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /

Tried main in module cal. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ViewDoesNotExist
```

and here are my url patterns:

```
(r"^(\d+)/$", "main"),
(r"", "main"),
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

I am confused though, because it appears to me that the function "main" does exist in views.py, as shown below.  Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
import time
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response

from dbe.cal.models import *

mnames = "January February March April May June July August September October November December"
mnames = mnames.split()


@login_required
def main(request, year=None):
"""Main listing, years and months; three years per page."""
# prev / next years
if year: year = int(year)
else:    year = time.localtime()[0]

nowy, nowm = time.localtime()[:2]
lst = []

# create a list of months for each year, indicating ones that contain entries and current
for y in [year, year+1, year+2]:
    mlst = []
    for n, month in enumerate(mnames):
        entry = current = False   # are there entry(s) for this month; current month?
        entries = Entry.objects.filter(date__year=y, date__month=n+1)

        if entries:
            entry = True
        if y == nowy and n+1 == nowm:
            current = True
        mlst.append(dict(n=n+1, name=month, entry=entry, current=current))
    lst.append((y, mlst))

return render_to_response("cal/main.html", dict(years=lst, user=request.user, year=year,
                                               reminders=reminders(request)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the `main` function does not exist in the `cal` module -- that is correct, it exists in the `cal.views` module.

If you change your url patterns to the following, it should work:

```
(r"^(\d+)/$", "cal.views.main"),
# (r"", "cal.views.main"),
```

I have commented out the `r""` url above, because it is a catch all url. It appears above your pattern for the login url, so your `main` view is handling the log url `/accounts/login/`. The `main` view uses the `login_required` decorator, causing a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

Alasdair's answer is correct.
I just want to add a bonus from : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/#simplifying-the-urlconfs

You can declare it this way for more convenience :) :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('cal.views',
                       (r'^(\d+)/$', 'main'),
                       (r'', 'main'),
)
```

Comment: tried this and suggestion from @Alasdair, but now I get a "problem loading page" error in the browser, and when I look at the dev server's log it shows that it's trying to "GET" a page that doesn't exist:   '"GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Nov/2011 14:14:42] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Nov/2011 14:14:42] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/accounts/login/%253Fnext%253D/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0'

Comment: Your catch all url `r""` is causing a redirect loop. I've explained more in my answer.